# Which function should I use so that it works just like GOTO statement?

Tags: c++

I am learning c++ and I have this question.

I have a file01.cpp with loops and if else statement.

e.g.

File01.cpp has

```
If(x<0)
cout<<x<<endl;
else
GOTO file02.cpp line number 29;
```

This the the rough idea what I want to do. I don't know how can I do this, I preferrably don't want to use GOTO statement.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense.  Presumably file2 contains (at least) one function; just call that function.

Comment: You can't, there is no notion of "files" and "lines" in a compiled program. Put a function there.

Comment: What does file02.cpp look like, in the vicinity of line 29?

Comment: Let me restate your question: You want to do a goto, but you don't want to use goto. Why? I mean... *why* do you think a goto is the solution to your problem? and *why* don't you want to use `goto`? I really don't understand either.

Comment: Your will is wrong. You should never want to go to file02.cpp line number 29. You should always want to execute the code which is inside a function, i.e. to call a function.

Comment: You can't use GOTO like that. And avoid using GOTO. And if you want to include a part of another file in your program why don't you write a header file with the function defined in it. You then include the header file in your program.

Comment: You do realize all of your code would break if you added a comment, say, on file02.cpp, line 21?

Answer (score 6):

> Which function should I use so that it works just like GOTO statement?

You shouldn't. The point of avoiding `goto` is to avoid the kind of spaghetti code it produces, not to avoid the literal word `goto`. By substituting some other function for `goto`, you've completely missed the point. You need to restructure your program, and invoke a function, not a line number.

To answer the question you've actually asked, what you should use for `goto`-like behaviour *is* `goto`; there is no "function" that behaves like `goto`, because `goto` already does that. But the more important answer is, *don't do what you're doing*, rethink how your program is structured.

Answer (score 2):

You want to factor out that code you want to call `(file02.cpp line number 29)` into a function and call that function from file01.cpp and file02.cpp line number 29

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you would structure your c++ or c programs. Instead you would use a functional approach. (err I mean Procedural)

By this I mean you would have a function inside a header file, and you would call that function. Not `goto` it.

Comment: Be careful; ["functional" doesn't mean what you intend it to mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming)...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Good point, I have changed my phrase to "function-oriented". I was originally thinking object oriented, but in this case probably OOP is a steep hill to throw at him.

Comment: @EdwardBird Perhaps you were looking for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming

Comment: @Thomas I'll rephrase it